# Spanning Trees in Answer Set Programming

Tags: graph, logic-programming, answer-set-programming, spanning-tree

For the undirected graph described below, I am trying to get its spanning trees and then separate its leaves from the internal nodes. Could you please help me with my code ?

What I expect to see after running the code is something like :

*Answer 1 : spanTree(1,2), spanTree(2,3), spanTree(3,4), leaf(1), leaf(4), internal(2), internal(3).*

*Answer 2 : spanTree(1,2), spanTree(1,3), spanTree(3,4), leaf(2), leaf(4), internal(1), internal(3).*

```
% undirected graph
edge(1,2).
edge(2,3).
edge(1,3).
edge(3,4).
vertex(X):- edge(X,Y).
vertex(X):- edge(Y,X).

%find spanning trees
spanTree(X,Y):- edge(X,Y).
spanTree(X,Y):- edge(Y,X).

start(1).

reached(X):-start(X).
reached(X):-reached(Y), spanTree(Y,X).
    
:-spanTree(X,Y), start(Y).
:-spanTree(X,Y), spanTree(X1,Y), X != X1.
:-vertex(X), not reached(X).

% degree of vertex
degree(X,D) :- vertex(X),D=#count {Y :spanTree(X,Y)}.

% leaves and internal vertices
{leaf(X):- spanTree(X,_),degree(X,D), D=1}:- vertex(X).
{internal(X):- spanTree(X,_),degree(X,D), D>1}:- vertex(X).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid counting unless necessary. I mirrored the edges at start to implement the undirected graph and guessing the spanTree is also important. I made a shortcut here: instead of saying, an edge might be a spantree-edge, when "building" I say: for every node (except root) choose exactly one ingoing edge to be the spantree-edge.
The reached part is pretty much copy & paste (good job here), but I left out the first two constraints because they are already covered.
The internal/leaf classification can also be simplified. Deriving internal nodes is easy, leafs can be covered by not being internals.

```
edge(1,2). edge(2,3). edge(1,3). edge(3,4).
% mirror edges
edge(Y,X) :- edge(X,Y).
vertex(X) :- edge(_,X).

% every node Y except root has exactly one ingoing edge
{ spanTree(X,Y) : edge(X,Y) } == 1:- vertex(Y), not root(Y).

root(1).
reached(X) :- root(X).
reached(X) :- reached(Y), spanTree(Y,X).
    
:- vertex(X), not reached(X).

% an internal node has an outgoing edge
internal(X) :- spanTree(X,_).
% a vertex which is not an internal is a leaf
leaf(X) :- vertex(X), not internal(X).

#show spanTree/2.
#show leaf/1.
#show internal/1.
```

Output

```
Answer: 1
internal(3) leaf(2) leaf(4) internal(1) spanTree(3,2) spanTree(1,3) spanTree(3,4)
Answer: 2
internal(3) leaf(2) leaf(4) internal(1) spanTree(1,2) spanTree(1,3) spanTree(3,4)
Answer: 3
internal(3) leaf(4) internal(1) spanTree(1,2) internal(2) spanTree(2,3) spanTree(3,4)
SATISFIABLE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. yes this seems to work better.. I do not get why in "Answer 3" vertex "1" is internal and not leaf.. (its degree in the spanning tree is 1) @DuDa

Comment: @john_b ... 1 is the root. It is never a leaf except if there are no other nodes.

Comment: for my understanding leafes are nodes without children.

Comment: oh yes.. you are correct